# XLSX writer for PHP for big data

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have used PHPExcel and Spout libraries for outputting XLSX or CSV files. the problem is that both of them exceed PHP execution time (30s) and PHPExcel also exceeds RAM usage limit on big data export (something like 2M records)

Is there any other way to address this problem without increasing execution time and export large file under 30s? (Time is first priority and RAM usage is the second priority).

Comment: Depends on your needs.... if you don't need XLSX, but purely CSV, then use PHP's built-in `fputcsv()`

Comment: Otherwise, look at using [php_excel and libxl](https://gist.github.com/belgattitude/999aee8eb6bd73fd0a7367ad896c76c3)

Comment: @MarkBaker I get time-out on `fputcsv()`

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you have any benchmark for `libxl`? The php version is 5.6

Comment: No I don't have any benchmarks..... libxl is native C, so doesn't use PHP memory at all, and some basic benchmarks done by others can be found [here](https://blog.mayflower.de/4922-Performant-Handling-Excel-Files-PHP.html)

Comment: But if you get a timeout on fputcsv() you really have a serious data volume/speed problem elsewhere

Comment: I also believe that Ilia has updated the php_excel wrapper for libxl to work with PHP7 if necessary, but it should certainly work with PHP5.6

Comment: And note that libxl isn't free, but requires a license payment